# Cannot display Chinese words after iText flattenFields methods? How to create PdfFont() with 2 TTF font files?

Tags: fonts, itext, cjk

I am using iText PDF ligrary to create PDF with following steps:

1. Manually create a PDF with form fields (e.g. text box) with input Chinese words
2. Some input Chinese words are rendered by PMINGLIU.ttf while some Chinese words are rendered by PMINGLIU-ExtB.ttf
3. Use iText to perform flattenFields method to flatten the PDF

Question 1: After iText PDF flattening, the Chinese words cannot be rendered. How to solve?

Question 2: I require 2 TTF font files (i.e. PMINGLIU.ttf and PMINGLIU-ExtB.ttf) for rendering different Chinese characters (e.g.  in PMINGLIU-ExtB.ttf and 李 in PMINGLIU.ttf), how can I use PdfFormField.setFont() with 2 TTF fonts?

Question 3: Is it possible to create PdfFont() by 2 TTF font files (i.e. PMINGLIU.ttf and PMINGLIU-ExtB.ttf)?

Thank you for your hints!

1. I tried to PdfAcroForm.flattenFields() but cannot display Chinese words.
2. I tried to use PdfFormField.setFont() but it only accept 1 font.  The Chinese content has some characters rendered by PMINGLIU.ttf while some characters rendered by PMINLIU-ExtB.ttf. How to use PdfFormField.setFont() with 2 fonts?
3. Is it possible to create PdfFont() by 2 TTF font files?